# setUserVisibleHint() throwing NullPointerException when calling getActivity()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have create 3 Fragments which are in a ViewPager. I am trying to get data from the server only when the particular Fragment is visible to the user. For that I have called my web service method in setUserVisibleHint(). But I am get NullPointerException when I am using getActivity() inside that method. How can I make sure I that I load data only once and when its visible to the user ? Here the code:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser && !_areLecturesLoaded){
            if(getActivity() == null){ //this is always null
                Log.e("Fragment1","No Activity");
            }else{
                getLatLong();
            }
            _areLecturesLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    private void getLatLong() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                // The next two lines tell the new client that “this” current class will handle connection stuff
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                //fourth line adds the LocationServices API endpoint from GooglePlayServices
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
```

I have verified that onAttach() method is getting called after setUserVisibleHint(). Before Activity is attached setUserVisibleHint() is firing up.

Comment: Check  if fragment is added to the activity before calling `getActivity()`.call `isAdded()`to check it.

Comment: setUserVisibleHint() is getting called before onAttach() method. That means before the fragment is getting attached the setUserVisibleHint() method is getting fired. How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
boolean isVisible=false;
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isVisible=isVisibleToUser;

}

 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    if(visible){
    // do what you must todo
    }else{
     //do what you must todo
    }

}
```

Comment: In the above code. `case FRAGMENT1:` is not called when the fragment is loaded for the first time. But after a swipe the `onPageSelected()` is working for `FRAGMENT2` and `FRAGMENT3`. And if I come back to `FRAGMENT1` then `case FRAGMENT1:` is getting called.

Comment: First time its loading the data. But if I swipe and come back to the fragment.No data is loading.

Comment: just check if you load data before don't load again else load

Comment: i m directly calling the network operation inside `if(visible){ }` Is that fine?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a Activity reference when `onAttach()` is called and use it everywhere instead of `getActivity()`
Like this:

```
@Override 
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            mActivity = activity;
            }
```