# Launch Service in setUserVisibleHint

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to work with `Fragment`, `ViewPager` and `TabLayout`.
now I have a problem with starting service command in my fragment.

I have my service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  ....
}
```

And I want that when I change tab in my TabLayout the fragment selected make request to service.

So I have tried this:

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), myService.class);
        msgIntent.setAction("INIT_REQUEST");
        msgIntent.putExtra("id", sectionNumber);
        msgIntent.putExtras(extras);
        getActivity().startService(msgIntent);

    }
```

But the problem is throw an Exception in **getActivity()** because it is null:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on
>   a null object reference

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: viewPager always loads only one fragment ahead of current. So let's say you have 3 fragments and you are at first one. Now when you will go to 2nd fragment setUserVisibleHint won't be null because that fragment was already loaded but when you will go to third from first fragment it will through you the exception so you safe bet it to start a service onCreate of fragment.

Comment: thankyou, so with a simple if(getActivity() != null) I will resolve if I undestand that you said

Comment: by using if(getActivity() != null) your app won't crash but still you will get null. So to avoid that you need to run your service in onCreate or onAttach() of fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`viewPager` always loads only one `fragment` ahead of current. So let's say you have 3 `fragments` and you are at first one. Now when you will go to 2nd fragment `setUserVisibleHint` won't be null because that `fragment` was already loaded but when you will go to third from first fragment it will throw the exception so your safe bet it to start a service `onCreate` of fragment or you can also do it in `onAttach()` of your fragment.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), myService.class);
    msgIntent.setAction("INIT_REQUEST");
    msgIntent.putExtra("id", sectionNumber);
    msgIntent.putExtras(extras);
    getActivity().startService(msgIntent);
    }
```

and while using check if your activity is null or not.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
 if (((MainActivity) getActivity() != null) {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), myService.class);
    msgIntent.setAction("INIT_REQUEST");
    msgIntent.putExtra("id", sectionNumber);
    msgIntent.putExtras(extras);
    getActivity().startService(msgIntent);
  }
}
```

Also take a look at this answer. It might help you.
[setUserVisibleHint() throwing NullPointerException when calling getActivity()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856983/setuservisiblehint-throwing-nullpointerexception-when-calling-getactivity)

Comment: @LorenzoBerti  yes when you go from tab1 to tab2, tab2 is already loaded so onAttach() won't be called. So that's why I said to use onCreate() and do a check on setUserVisibleHint() if it's null then the service can be run through onCreate().

Comment: I have used this approach.
in on attach I call always service, for any fragment, but, I send broadcast personal for fragment section, before it doesn't work because I register unique broadcast for all fragment, so whe the tab1 send broadcast for send data from service to fragment, event tab2 get same data. so I have simple change in my service the logic of broadcast receiver

Comment: It seems so! I will test but for now, seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

Add `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager` and override `onPageSelected`. You can send command to your service from there.

Also if you have small number of fragments which are not very heavy you can call `setOffsPageLimit(int limit)` on ViewPager to keep more fragments in memory, this should avoid `NullPointerException`.

**Note:** This also depends on your pager adapter implementation.